# When open a product in multi-store website it redirects to 404 - page not found

Tags: magento, http-status-code-404, multiple-sites

I have **Multi-Store Magento Website**, that is managed by **only One Admin**

in one of its store website,

when i click on product name, it redirects me to **404 page**.

what can be the problem ??

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Re-index the site at `Admin -> System -> Index Management` then clear your cache at `Admin -> System -> Cache Management`.

Answer (score 0):

There is some cases that this could happen :-

1 - Make sure the product assigned to the store you want ( in catalog->manage products ) and then click on the products and you will find on the left tabs ( Websites ) make sure it checked to the stores.

2 - The product is disabled in this store/store view ( in product edit page ) change store ( Choose Store View ) to the store/store view you want and make sure product is Enabled.

3- You might be checking catalog category product url ( from url_rewrites ) which it could be not valid so it leads to 404.

Apart from this the catalog do reindex to your catalog product flat ( if you are using flat tables )

And also you can check the product if its exist with it direct view url ( no the re written url )

try ( www.your-store.com/store_view/catalog/product/view/id/product_id )

if The above link works ( so check the above steps and run all the indexers and try again ).